# Bootstrap well - using a well up to certain element or width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 4 spans stretched across the page and want to apply a well to the first three. This would leave the well wrapped around the first 3 spans giving them a background margin etc...

I used ended the well div just before the 4th span however it still stretches across the page moving the 4th span below. Yes I could apply css to position but want to avoid if possible. See bootply - http://bootply.com/71961

```
        <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="well">
                            <ul class="thumbnails">
                    <li class="span3">
                    <div class="thumbnail searchthumb">
                        <a href="#"><img alt="200x200" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></a>


                    </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span3">
                    <div class="thumbnail searchthumb">
                        <a href="#"><img alt="200x200" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></a>

                    </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span3">
                    <div class="thumbnail searchthumb">
                        <a href="#"><img alt="200x200" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></a>

                    </div>
                    </li>
                    </div>
                    <li class="span3">
                    <div class="thumbnail searchthumb">
                        <a href="#"><img alt="200x200" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></a>

                    </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A well adds padding so you have to be careful how you use it or you could break the grid, as is happeing with your example.

Here's a variation which looks promising: http://bootply.com/71967

You will see that

- I've created a new span9 column which holds a new well div (to prevent the grid from breaking)
- inside the well I'm using a nested row-fluid grid
- I've changed the nested columns to span4 (it's a nested row-fluid grid so they add to 12)
- The fourth li in your example was missing its ul parent

Good luck